# How to solve this ODE using given substitution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $a(x)$ is a solution to $$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{du}{dx}+c(x)u=0$$ Using the substitution $u(x)=a(x)v(x)$, find a first order ODE for $\frac{dv}{dx}$

Attempt:

From $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{du}{dx}+c(x)u=0$, we have: $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{du}{dx}+b(x)\frac{du}{dx}+c(x)u=0$$Now, from $u(x)=a(x)v(x)$ $$\frac{d}{dx}(a'v+av')+b(a'v+av')+cav=0$$ $$a''v+a'v'+a'v'+av''+ba'v+bav'+cav=0$$ $$2a'v'+a''v+av''+ba'v+bav'+cav=0$$
Let $z=\frac{dv}{dx}=v'$
$$2a'z+a''v+az'+ba'v+baz+cav=0$$ $$z(2a'+ba)+a''v+az'+ba'v+cav=0$$
I'm stuck here now...
The answer says $$z(2a'+ba)+az'=0$$ which is in my answer on the last line above, but I have extra terms. (note, at the start of the question I said: Suppose $a(x)$ is a solution, but I never used this fact - I assume that's the key to my mistake somewhere). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

The equation

$z(2a'+ba)+a''v+az'+ba'v+cav=0 \tag 1$

may be written

$z(2a'+ba) +az' + a''v+ba'v+cav=0, \tag 2$

or

$z(2a'+ba) +az' + (a''+ba'+ca)v=0; \tag 3$

we can now use

$a''+ba'+ca = 0 \tag 4$

i.e., that $a$ is a solution of (4), to conclude

$z(2a'+ba) +az'=0, \tag 5$

as required.

Comment: Damn! That is awesome and clever - thanks! :)

Comment: You are most welcome, sir!

Comment: @Isham:  got it, thanks!